# Nvidia-smi low GPU Utilization

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu, nvidia-geforce

I have a Titan X and have been running the [Breakout simulation](https://github.com/devsisters/DQN-tensorflow)  for over two days now and it's only `7%` through training and `nvidia-smi` is showing that it's only using `4-5%`. The `README.md` says that it only took 30 hours on a 980. That doesn't seem right. According to `main.py`, it should be using 100% by default if I don't give the flag. `nvidia-smi -i 0 -q -d MEMORY,UTILIZATION,POWER,CLOCK,COMPUTE` shows that FB Memory Usage is `11423 MiB/ 12185 Mib`. Am I interpreting `nvidia-smi` correctly? Is there something wrong with my GPU?

Comment: With `nvidia-smi`you normally should also see the processes running on the GPU. I think the GPU itself is ok, but the problem seems to be somewhere in the software stack that is used ( opencv, tensorflow, ... ) which does not make use of GPU computing.

Comment: Yeah, so I can see the process running. It's odd. When I run another implementation of this from another repo, it utilizes around 30% max. I looked around and it seems that a good amount of people are having the same issue with TensorFlow and TItan X. I haven't found any fixes yet. In another post, someone did suggest increasing the batch sizes since the TitanX has 12 GB of memory. Makes sense since this implementation used a 980 GPU, which is much weaker than a TItan X, but doesn't make sense because the code explicitly sets the util to 100% of the GPU. So....idk :/

Comment: I do have similar issue.